# Xdebug with event source

Tags: javascript, php, xdebug, eventsource

I have some kind of problem when starting in PhpStorm debugging application.

When I access URL where I debug my application there is additional event source request (SSE) made for notifications system. But when debugging is working it causes a problem that I can't refresh page, it's just loading indefinitely - I don't have any breakpoint to be sure. Immediately after I stop debugging session it loads.

What's going on? Can I somehow disable xdebug for this certain URL?

My code for those notifications looks like this:

```
public function moreAction()
{
    ob_start();
    $maxId = $this->request->getQuery('maxId', 'int');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
    while (1) {
        $result = $this->notificationService->more($maxId);
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as &$row) {
                if (!empty($row['data'])) {
                    $row['data'] = json_decode($row['data'], true);
                }
            }
            $maxId = $result[0]['id'];
            echo "event: message\n";
            echo "data:".json_encode($result);
            echo "\n\n";
            $this->doFlush();
        }
        sleep(5);
    }
}

protected function doFlush()
{
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        // Disable gzip in PHP.
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
        // Force disable compression in a header.
        // Required for flush in some cases (Apache + mod_proxy, nginx, php-fpm).
        header('Content-Encoding: none');
    }
    // Fill-up 4 kB buffer (should be enough in most cases).
    echo str_pad('', 4 * 1024);
    // Flush all buffers.
    do {
        $flushed = @ob_end_flush();
    } while ($flushed);
    @ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Comment: *"Can I somehow disable xdebug for this certain URL"* URL -- no. Script (the entry point) -- yes. But if all requests are served via single entry point (like almost all of the modern frameworks work these days) then obviously it will not be an option.

Comment: I may suggest to increase number of simultaneous debug sessions in PhpStorm for xdebug (by default it's 1). Whatever starts a second session maybe you will be able to see where it comes from (request data). No concrete idea on your case .. but, for example, it might be request for non-existing favicon.ico (unlikely to be your case, but just to give some idea).

Comment: Well yea but session should disable on some point. Well i just made a workaround to make a eventsource request only on production.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem while debugging SSE using xdebug. A workaround is to close the event source if leaving the page.

Assuming you are using javascript on the client side to request the eventsource like

```
let eventSource = new EventSource("moreAction.php")
```

put something like

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    eventSource.close();
});
```

in your page.

BTW, it's not a good idea to use `while(1)` in your eventsource loop, as it will loop infinitely, with exact the behavior you are experiencing. A timeout in the range 30-120 s is sensible and will you allow to continue debugging even if the eventsource isn't closed. After all, it is getting automatically reconnected.